Get timezone for specific date
I have a list of dates formatted like so:
'2024-01-01`

I need to turn them into ISO datetimes like so:
`2024-01-01T00:00:00-08:00`

I thought this would be easy, I was wrong.  I've seen many questions talk about this on SO, but they tend to over look the complexity of daylight savings time (DST).
What can't be used in a solution:
   datetime.now()

Using datetime.now() will give the current timezone, on the date it is today, and will not be relevant to the date in question.
I need to return the proper offest, when converting a specific date, based on what the offset would have been in local time at the date in question.  Example:
'2024-01-01' # becomes
'2024-01-01T00:00:00-08:00'

'2024-06-06' # becomes
'2024-01-01T00:00:00-07:00'

I have a solution to brute force this by calculating daylight savings time start and finishes.  But that's an ugly solution, there has to be some manipulation of the datetime api that works better.

What you're trying to do is impossible. Given a date as "2024-01-01" (and that's all the information you have) how can you possibly know if DST was applicable on that day without knowing where in the world that date was applied to your data?

@SIGHUP - you have the OS of the machine processing the data.  That's where you get the time zone.

from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def get_iso_datetime_with_timezone(date_str):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

    aware_datetime_utc = pytz.utc.localize(date_obj)

    timezone = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')  # Example timezone, replace with your desired timezone

    aware_datetime_timezone = aware_datetime_utc.astimezone(timezone)

    iso_datetime_with_timezone = aware_datetime_timezone.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

    return iso_datetime_with_timezone

dates = ['2024-01-01', '2024-06-06']

for date_str in dates:
    iso_datetime_with_timezone = get_iso_datetime_with_timezone(date_str)
    print(f'{date_str} => {iso_datetime_with_timezone}')}

ensure you replace 'America/Los_Angeles' with the appropriate timezone for your use case you can find the list of supported timezones in the pytz documentation
pytz handles historical timezone data so it will correctly account for DST changes on the specified date
NES ANSWER
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def get_iso_datetime_with_timezone(date_str, tz_name='America/Los_Angeles'):
    # Parse input date string to naive datetime object
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    aware_datetime = date_obj.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tz_name))
    
    iso_datetime_with_timezone = aware_datetime.isoformat()
    
    return iso_datetime_with_timezone


dates = ['2024-01-01', '2024-06-06']

for date_str in dates:
    iso_datetime_with_timezone = get_iso_datetime_with_timezone(date_str)
    print(f'{date_str} => {iso_datetime_with_timezone}')



I'm testing this now.  the line using astimezone at least is wrong, because it actually changes the datetime (converts from utc) instead of just adding the offset.

aware_datetime_utc.astimezone(timezone) should be aware_datetime_utc.replace(tzinfo=timezone).  Also, my testing gives an offset of 07:53 regardless of DST.

So, I got it working.  It turns out pytz is depreciated and the new package is here.  Appreciate you getting me on the right track.  If you want to update your answer I can mark it right.
